# Filtering a Cell Array with Recursion

Tags: arrays, matlab, recursion, filtering, cell-array

I'm pretty close on this problem. What I have to do is filter out a cell array. The cell array can have a variety of items in it, but what I want to do is pull out the strings, using recursion. I am pretty close on this one. I just have an issue when the cells have spaces in them. This is what I should get:

```
 Test Cases:

       cA1 = {'This' {{{[1:5] true} {' '}} {'is '} false true} 'an example.'};
       [filtered1] = stringFilter(cA1)
           filtered1 => 'This is an example.'

       cA2 = {{{{'I told '} 5:25 'her she'} {} [] [] ' knows'} '/take aim and reload'};
       [filtered2] = stringFilter(cA2)
           filtered2 => 'I told her she knows/take aim and reload'
```

Here is what I have:

```
%find the strings in the cArr and then concatenate them. 
function [Str] = stringFilter(in)
Str = [];
for i = 1:length(in)
    %The base case is a single cell
    if length(in) == 1
        Str = ischar(in{:,:});
    %if the length>1 than go through each cell and find the strings. 
       else
        str = stringFilter(in(1:end-1));
        if ischar(in{i})
            Str = [Str in{i}];
    elseif iscell(in{i}) 
            str1 = stringFilter(in{i}(1:end-1));
            Str = [Str str1];

        end
    end

end

end
```

I tried to use 'ismember', but that didn't work. Any suggestions? My code outputs the following:

```
      filtered1 => 'This an example.'
      filtered2 => '/take aim and reload'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can quite simplify your function to

```
function [Str] = stringFilter(in)
Str = [];
for i = 1:length(in)
    if ischar(in{i})
        Str = [Str in{i}];
    elseif iscell(in{i})
        str1 = stringFilter(in{i});
        Str = [Str str1];
    end
end

end
```

Just loop through all elements in the cell a test, whether it is a string or a cell. In the latter, call the function for this cell again. Output:

```
>> [filtered1] = stringFilter(cA1)

filtered1 =

This is an example.

>> [filtered2] = stringFilter(cA2)

filtered2 =

I told her she knows/take aim and reload
```

Comment: OKay, that actually makes sense :) Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a different implememntation

```
function str = stringFilter(in)
if ischar(in)
    str = in;
elseif iscell(in) && ~isempty(in)
    str = cell2mat(cellfun(@stringFilter, in(:)', 'uni', 0));
else
    str = '';
end
end
```

If it's string, return it. If it is a cell apply the same function on all of the elements and concatenate them. Here I use `in(:)'` to make sure it is a row vector and then `cell2mat` concatenates resulting strings. And if the type is anything else return an empty string. We need to check if the cell array is empty or not because `cell2mat({})` is of type `double`.

Comment: I understand that, but cell2mat is generally frowned up since we weren't taught to use it

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
    Str = ischar(in{:,:});
```

is the problem. It doesn't make any sense to me.

You're close to the getting the answer, but made a few significant but small mistakes.

You need to check for these things:
1. Loop over the cells of the input.
2. For each cell, see if it itself is a cell, if so, call stringFilter on the cell's VALUE
3. if it is not a cell but is a character array, then use its VALUE as it is.
4. Otherwise if the cell VALUE contains a non character, the contribution of that cell to the output is '' (blank)

I think you made a mistake by not taking advantage of the difference between in(1) and in{1}.
Anyway, here's my version of the function. It works.

```
function [out] = stringFilter(in)
out = [];

for idx = 1:numel(in)
    if iscell (in{idx})
        % Contents of the cell is another cell array
        tempOut = stringFilter(in{idx});
    elseif ischar(in{idx})
        % Contents are characters
        tempOut = in{idx};
    else
        % Contents are not characters
        tempOut = '';
    end

    % Concatenate the current output to the overall output
    out = [out, tempOut];
end

end
```